merge legends together in ggplot after using ggarrange
I have multiple dataframes, one from each of 13 sites, with mean abundance data of 90 different species which scaled down looks like:
 site1<-data.frame(species = LETTERS[1:26], abundance = sample(x = 1:10, rep = TRUE, size = 26))
 site2<-data.frame(species = LETTERS[1:26], abundance = sample(x = 1:10, rep = TRUE, size = 26))
 site3<-data.frame(species = LETTERS[1:26], abundance = sample(x = 1:10, rep = TRUE, size = 26))
 site4<-data.frame(species = LETTERS[1:26], abundance = sample(x = 1:10, rep = TRUE, size = 26))  

And what I want to achieve is a grid of bar charts with the top 10 most abundant species from each site in descending order. For which I use:
 site1plot<-ggplot(head(site1,10), aes(x=reorder(species, - abundance), y=abundance, fill = species)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
 site2plot<-ggplot(head(site2,10), aes(x=reorder(species, - abundance), y=abundance, fill = species)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
 site3plot<-ggplot(head(site3,10), aes(x=reorder(species, - abundance), y=abundance, fill = species)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
 site4plot<-ggplot(head(site4,10), aes(x=reorder(species, - abundance), y=abundance, fill = species)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
 ggarrange(site1plot,site2plot,site3plot,site4plot, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")

My issue is, because the different sites all have different top 10 species, the legend doesn't fit with all of them, and even if I could make it include all the species I need the charts all have different colours for each species depending on the order. If I don't do common legend the chart gets super messy as I have 13 sites and having them gridded with a legend below each is a bit much. I'm hoping there's an easy fix for this? Any help much appreciated!
My issue is, the top 10 species differ between sites, and

Another potential option is to combine and plot all of the data using facets, e.g.
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

site1<-data.frame(species = LETTERS[1:26], abundance = sample(x = 1:10, rep = TRUE, size = 26))
site2<-data.frame(species = LETTERS[1:26], abundance = sample(x = 1:10, rep = TRUE, size = 26))
site3<-data.frame(species = LETTERS[1:26], abundance = sample(x = 1:10, rep = TRUE, size = 26))
site4<-data.frame(species = LETTERS[1:26], abundance = sample(x = 1:10, rep = TRUE, size = 26))  

bind_rows(site1, site2, site3, site4, .id = "site") %>%
  slice_max(n = 10, order_by = abundance,
            by = site, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder_within(x = species, by = -abundance,
                                within = site, sep = ""),
             y = abundance,
             fill = species)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~site, scales = "free_x",
             labeller = as_labeller(\(x) paste("Site:", x))) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 4)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.title.x = element_blank())


Created on 2024-04-04 with reprex v2.1.0

To get a common legend set the limits= of the fill scale to include all species used in any of the single plots:
set.seed(123)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

site_data <- list(site1, site2, site3, site4) |>
  lapply(\(x) x[order(x$abundance), ] |> head(10))

# Get a list of all species used in any of the plots
limits_fill <- lapply(site_data, `[[`, "species") |>
  unlist() |>
  unique()

site_plots <- site_data |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    ggplot(
      x,
      aes(x = reorder(species, -abundance), y = abundance, fill = species)
    ) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = TRUE) +
      scale_fill_discrete(limits = limits_fill)
  })

ggarrange(plotlist = site_plots, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")


